# How to move values from 2nd array into the empty places of 1st array

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to move values from 2nd array into the empty places of 1st array

1st array as below

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 
    [2] => 4
    [3] => 
)
```

2nd array as below

```
Array
(
    [0] => 5
    [1] => 9

)
```

I want output as merging 2nd array into 1st as shown below

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 5
    [2] => 4
    [3] => 9
)
```

I have tried below code.....

```
for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++){
    for($j=$i; $j<=$i; $j++)
      if(empty($assign_taskk[$i])){
            $assign_taskk[$i] = $taskkk[$i];
       }
}
```

plz help me out for same

Comment: `array_merge($arr1,$arr2);`

Comment: What values have the empty places?

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile `array_merge` __merges__ arrays and not replaces values.

Comment: array_merge($arr1,$arr2);
This code giving me output as 

Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 
    [2] => 4
    [3] => 
    [4] => 5
    [5] => 9
)

But i want as below
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 5
    [2] => 4
    [3] => 9
)

Answer (score 0):

Lets say your arrays look like:

```
$a1 = [
    0 => 1,
    1 => null,
    2 => 4,
    3 => null,
];

$a2 = [
    0 => null,
    1 => 5,
    2 => null,
    3 => 9,
];
```

Then you can iterate over first array and add values from the second one when needed:

```
foreach ($a1 as $k => $v) {
    if (empty($v) && !empty($a2[$k])) {
        $a1[$k] = $a2[$k];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it using below way-

```
<?php
$arr1= [1,null,4,null];
$arr2 = [null,5,null,9];
$result = array_values(array_filter($arr1) + array_filter($arr2));
print_r($result)
?>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/R4aeE

Answer (score 0):

```
Hi @amod try this        
$_newArray = array_values(array_filter($array1) + array_filter($array2));
print_r($_newArray);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, once see my array as i mentioned below
1st array
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 
    [2] => 4
    [3] => 
)

2nd array
Array
(
    [0] => 5
    [1] => 9

)

I Want result as below
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 5
    [2] => 4
    [3] => 9
)
Please recommend and help me for the same

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code for this:

```
$firstArray = [1,'',4,''];
$secondArray = [5,9];

$secondArrayCounter = 0;
foreach($firstArray as $key => $value) {
    if (empty($value)) {
        $firstArray[$key] = $secondArray[$secondArrayCounter];
        $secondArrayCounter++;
    }
}
print_r($firstArray);
```

Hope it helps you.